# How to call a method (array.length times) passing as arguments key and each array item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this:

```
const data = {
          Products: [{name:'x', price:'y'}, 
                     {name:'x', price:'y'},
                     {name:'x',price:'y'}]
             }
```

and a method which will call an api:

```
actions.saveItem({
                name: moduleName(Products in this case),
                values (each object of the array) 
                )}
```

**How to call my method 3 times with the arguments("Products" and each object on the array)**

Comment: use ``forEach loop

Comment: what about `values: Products`?

Comment: Please don't add [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056979) repeatedly. If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, @ the users who close it and explain why it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Just iterate with a forEach loop over `Products` array and get the product object at every iteration and add it as your `values`. Also use `async` `await` if it is an api call.

Comment: @adiga, i was thinking that the duplicate post is removed from questions totally, thats why i created new one

Comment: Gold badge users for a tag can close and open duplicate questions with a single vote. Reply them and explain / seek clarifications. They will open the question or a find better duplicate target that answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling arrays and asynchronous functions, the couple `Array.map` and `await Promise.all` is the soluce!

You are calling the save function for each element of the array and creates a new array of Promises objects that you resolve using a `Promise.all`.

All the saves are going to be made concurrently. You wait until all is done.

```js
const data = {
  Products: [{
      name: 'x',
      price: 'y'
    },
    {
      name: 'x',
      price: 'y'
    },
    {
      name: 'x',
      price: 'y'
    },
  ],
};

function saveItem(x) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Resolve one save!'), 100);
  });
}

(async() => {
  const rets = await Promise.all(data.Products.map(x => saveItem({
    name: 'Products',
    values: x,
  })));
  
  console.log(rets);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot, but my object will be much bigger. What if i dynamically want to loop through each key?

Comment: So you have to turn the `map` into a `reduce` and build a new array. This could be an other question